# How can a method be called for testing and not be executed?

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, service, karma-jasmine

Here's my Component :

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'app-signup',
    templateUrl: './signup.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./signup.component.scss']
})
export class SignUpComponent implements OnInit {
    specialLink: string;

    constructor( 
        private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
        private techService: TechService
 ) {}

ngOnInit() {
        this.specialLink = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params.id;

        if (this.specialLink !== undefined) {
            console.log('GOOD1');
            this.setSpecialSignup();
            console.log('GOOD3');
        }

setSpecialSignup() {
        console.log('GOOD2');
        this.techService.getStuff();
    }
```

And here's my tests :

```js
describe('SignUpComponent', () => {
  let component: SignUpComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<SignUpComponent>;
  let ActivatedRouteMock: any;
  
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    ActivatedRouteStub = {
      snapshot: {
        params: { id: 123 }
      },
    };

    TechServiceMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('TechService', ['getStuff']);
    TechServiceMock.getStuff.and.returnValue(new Promise((resolve, reject) => { resolve() }));

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ SignUpComponent ],
      imports: [ RouterTestingModule ],
      providers: [
        {provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: ActivatedRouteStub},
        {provide: TechService, useValue: TechServiceMock},  
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SignUpComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  });


  describe('to get special signup', () => {
      it('should call setSpecialSignup() one time when user is coming from special link', () => {
        spyOn(component, 'setSpecialSignup');
        ActivatedRouteStub.snapshot.params.id = "some_special_link";
        fixture.detectChanges();
        expect(component.setSpecialSignup).toHaveBeenCalled(); // it's working
      });

      it('should call TechService', () => {
        ActivatedRouteStub.snapshot.params.id = "123";
        fixture.detectChanges();
        expect(TechServiceMock.getStuff).toHaveBeenCalled(); // it's NOT working
      });
    });
```

I want to test if techService.getStuff() has been called. The service is in
setSpecialSignup() method in Signup component.

The method has been called when I test it, but the logs in console tells me otherwise. (It goes GOOD1 and GOOD3 without GOOD2, which is weird).

Maybe this is simple question, but is there any explenation for this ?
How can I test if TechServiceMock.getStuff() has been called ?
I tried different approaches to mock TechService but any of these helped.

What did I miss ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are looking for the callThrough() method, you can read more about it here: https://hatoum.com/blog/2016/11/12/jasmine-unit-testing-dont-forget-to-callthrough

Comment: Perfect ! The article is very informative and very clear, thanks a lot :)